# is it possible to store output of system call in windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows

E.G.: I want to store output of `system("dir");`

Comment: On the other hand, if "dir" isn't just an example, use FindFirstFile/FindNextFile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use redirection to a file (system( "dir > file" )), read that file and delete it or go the unnamed pipes way as in Unix - call CreatePipe() to create a pipe and attach it as the input/output stream in PROCESS_INFORMATION structure and pass that structure into CreateProcess().

Comment: yah i can tryout this simple thing, redirecting to a file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, look at capturing stdout from CreateProcess:

- [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499.aspx)

Note that `dir` is a built in command under DOS. So you'll have to do something like the following system command:

- `cmd.exe /c dir c:\path\to\directory`

rather than just calling `dir`.  Type `cmd /?` for more information on the `/c` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX has a popen() function and I think that Windows has something similar called _popen().

Comment: Which won't work with a Windows GUI app, only with a console.